# How to make a span put a newline for overflowing text

Tags: overflow

I'm trying to use the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/UNs9J/1/
HTML:

```
<p>Hover here<span>some text here ?</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
span{
background:#F8F8F8;
border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
color: #717171;
font-size: 13px;
height: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: -80px;
left:-30px;
display:none;
padding:0 20px;

}
span:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:-10px; 
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
background:#f8f8f8;
left:50%;
margin-left:-10px;
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}
p{
margin:100px;
float:left;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
}

p:hover span{
display:block;
}
```

So, my problem is, when the text is too long, how do I get it to put the overflowing part in a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
span{
background:#F8F8F8;
border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
color: #717171;
font-size: 13px;
height: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: -80px;
left:-30px;
display:none;
padding:0 20px;

}
```

to

```
span{
background:#F8F8F8;
border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
color: #717171;
font-size: 13px;
height: auto;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: -80px;
left:-30px;
display:none;
padding:0 20px;

}
```

then you probably have to adjust the top-attribute to your needs.

Comment: That didn't make the height extend, it made the width extend. I want to wrap the text inside the span.

Comment: I fixed it with using word-wrap: break-word and made height auto. Thanks for your help though.